# json deserialize in java for different type of variable in same object

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, deserialization

I have two apis  which is return following json responses.

[image]

I created a class called 'Card' and how should I achieve 'expiry' field which have different type for particular request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could show your  attempt, also it would be better if you post the responses as code/text blocks, not images. You need either 2 classes, one for each API, or field of type `Object`, so it can be anything.

Comment: Do not use polymorphism, it is not well supported. Instead (if you own the contract) simplify the model (e.g. add `expirityString`, `expirityObject` and throw an exception if both are specified with different values).

Answer (score 5):

For simplicity I'll work only with card object from example, I won't be wrapping it another object. To avoid duplication in examples, I'll use this base class to hold common fields:

```
public abstract class BaseCard {

    private String brand;
    private String fundingMethod;
    private String scheme;

    //setters and getters
}
```

You have few options.

**Option 1:**
If you know which api you are getting response from, you can have two classes, each holding `expiry` in format specific for the api. When getting data from api 1 use:

```
public class CardApi1 extends BaseCard {

    private String expiry;

    //setters and getters
}
```

And for api 2:

```
public class CardApi2 extends BaseCard {

    private Expiry expiry;

    //setters and getters
}
```

The expiry object looks like this:

```
public class Expiry {

    private String month;
    private String year;

    //setters and getters
}
```

If you are calling api 1, deserialize to `CardApi1`, else to `CardApi2`.

**Option 2:** Make the expiry field `Object`, this way anything can be deserialized into it.

```
public class CardApiMixed extends BaseCard {

    private Object expiry;

    //setters and getters

    public String getExpiryAsString() {
        return (String) this.expiry;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getExpiryAsMap() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> expiry = (Map<String, Object>) this.expiry;
        return expiry;
    }
}
```

This way no matter which api you are calling, you deserialize into one class. The downside is, when retrieving `expiry`, you still have to know which api the data comes from, so you use correct method.

**Option 3:** Write custom deserializer which will resolve the field correctly, no matter which api is used. Personally I would go for this option. The deserializer is this:

```
public class ExpiryResolvingCardDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<CardApiResolved> {

    public ExpiryResolvingCardDeserializer() {
        super(CardApiResolved.class);
    }

    @Override
    public CardApiResolved deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
        CardApiResolved card = new CardApiResolved();
        card.setBrand(node.get("brand").asText());
        card.setFundingMethod(node.get("fundingMethod").asText());
        card.setScheme(node.get("scheme").asText());
        JsonNode expiryNode = node.get("expiry");
        Expiry expiry = new Expiry();
        if (expiryNode.isObject()) {
            //that's for api 2
            expiry.setMonth(expiryNode.get("month").asText());
            expiry.setYear(expiryNode.get("year").asText());
        } else {
            //for api 1
            String text = expiryNode.asText();
            //assuming format is always mmYY, you can handle it in differently if there are other options
            int splitIndex = 2;
            expiry.setMonth(text.substring(0, splitIndex));
            expiry.setYear(text.substring(splitIndex));
        }
        card.setExpiry(expiry);
        return card;
    }
}
```

To summarise it, when `expiry` node is object, handle it like an object to get month and year data from it, if it is a string, split it to extract month and year. Like this no matter the format, `expiry` is always resolved to `Expiry` class. The card class will look like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ExpiryResolvingCardDeserializer.class)
public class CardApiResolved extends BaseCard {

    private Expiry expiry;

    //setters and getters
}
```

Note the `JsonDeserialize` annotation specifying the deserializer to use for this type. And lastly, some unit tests to play with and check results. The api responses are files in the test resources.

```
public class CardApiTests {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void testCardApi1() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("card-api-1.json");
        //map to CardApi1, when calling api 1
        CardApi1 result = this.mapper.readValue(inputStream, CardApi1.class);
        assertEquals("0139", result.getExpiry());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCardApi2() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("card-api-2.json");
        //map to CardApi2, when calling api 2
        CardApi2 result = this.mapper.readValue(inputStream, CardApi2.class);
        assertEquals("1", result.getExpiry().getMonth());
        assertEquals("39", result.getExpiry().getYear());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCardApiMixed_Api1() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("card-api-1.json");
        CardApiMixed result = this.mapper.readValue(inputStream, CardApiMixed.class);
        assertEquals("0139", result.getExpiryAsString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCardApiMixed_Api2() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("card-api-2.json");
        CardApiMixed result = this.mapper.readValue(inputStream, CardApiMixed.class);
        assertEquals("1", result.getExpiryAsMap().get("month"));
        assertEquals("39", result.getExpiryAsMap().get("year"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCardApiResolved_Api1() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("card-api-1.json");
        CardApiResolved result = this.mapper.readValue(inputStream, CardApiResolved.class);
        assertEquals("01", result.getExpiry().getMonth());
        assertEquals("39", result.getExpiry().getYear());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCardApiResolved_Api2() throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("card-api-2.json");
        CardApiResolved result = this.mapper.readValue(inputStream, CardApiResolved.class);
        assertEquals("1", result.getExpiry().getMonth());
        assertEquals("39", result.getExpiry().getYear());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share how the expiry field is prepared? like

"expiery":"0139" = month+year.
if the field is prepared like this then you can keep variable type either String or list, you have needed a minor modification. You will give an idea according to the given example.

```java
   public class App {
    
        private static final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .build();
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .GET()
                    .uri(URI.create("https://jsonmock.abc.com/api/articles?page=3"))
                    .setHeader("User-Agent", "Java 11 HttpClient Bot") // add request header
                    .build();
    
            HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    
            // print response headers
            HttpHeaders headers = response.headers();
            headers.map().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ":" + v));
            String responseBody = response.body();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Object newJsonNode = mapper.readValue(responseBody, Object.class);
            Map<String, Object> objectMap = (Map) newJsonNode;
            if (objectMap.get("expiry") instanceof List) {
                //if I assume that expiry string created by appending month and year
                List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List) objectMap.get("expiry");
                Map<String, Object> map = list.get(0);
                String exp = (String) map.get("month") + (String) map.get("year");
                objectMap.put("expiry", exp);
                //then parse to direct object
            } else if (objectMap.get("expiry") instanceof String) {
                //then cast to dto
                //you can apply reverse logic here, i.e string to map
            }
        }
    }
```