# Deserialize Json with a JsonProperty with 2 different data types

Tags: java, json, deserialization

Can I deserialize ModelRequest object in either of these 2 formats. In one instance I should be able to pass Map<String, JsonNode> and another one passing just JsonNode for the property "input". But I do not want to create a separate class for these 2 variants, is there a way to achieve this?

```
public class ModelRequest implements Jsonable {

    @JsonProperty("models")
    private List<ModelParameterDTO> modelParameters;

    @JsonProperty("input")
    private Map<String, JsonNode> inputParameters;

}


public class ModelRequest implements Jsonable {

    @JsonProperty("models")
    private List<ModelParameterDTO> modelParameters;

    @JsonProperty("input")
    private JsonNode inputParameters;

}
```

When I ty this, I am getting error during runtime.

```
public class ModelRequest implements Jsonable {

    @JsonProperty("models")
    private List<ModelParameterDTO> modelParameters;

    @JsonProperty("input")
    private JsonNode inputParameters;

    @JsonProperty("input")
    private Map<String, JsonNode> inputParameters_1;
}
```

I also tried using @JsonSetter approach, but that is changing the Json property name "input" to the method name so it is no longer being "input".

Comment: Are you deserializing json string into `ModelRequest`, or are you serializing it into json string?

Comment: @Chaosfire I am deserializing json string into "Modelequest" object.

Comment: Ok, sounds to me like you need something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897528/json-deserialize-in-java-for-different-type-of-variable-in-same-object/70903626#70903626), option 3 in my answer. If this is not what you need, please provide some examples for the different json formats, that need to be deserialized into your model.