# Deserialize object that might be wrapped

Tags: java, jackson

I need to process JSON from different sources who use different models. One is sending me

```json
{
  "addressData": {
    "street": "Foostreet 1",
    "zip": "12345",
    "city": "Metropolis"
  }
}
```

and the other

```json
{
  "addressData": {
    "address": {
      "street": "Foostreet 1",
      "zip": "12345",
      "city": "Metropolis"
    }
  }
}
```

i.e. the inner contents are identical, there might just be one additional layer of wrapping. So far my Java model for deserializing looks like this

```java
class AddressData {
  private String street;
  private String zip;
  private String city;

  private Address address;
}

class Address {
  private String street;
  private String zip;
  private String city;
}
```

and I use an additional step in post-processing to normalize this.

Is there an annotation to tell Jackson that the object *might* be wrapped by an additional property, so that I can skip this boilerplate?

Comment: You should do two different models. The deserialize sources and then in the code manually convert one model to another.

Comment: I am not aware of such annotation (may be wrong though). The approaches in [json deserialize in java for different type of variable in same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897528/json-deserialize-in-java-for-different-type-of-variable-in-same-object) might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I settled for a custom delegating `JsonCreator` and manual mapping of the fields. Not perfect, but it will do for now. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know!

```java
class Address {
    private String street;
    private String zip;
    private String city;

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
    public Address(JsonNode node) {
        var address = Optional.ofNullable(node.get("address")).orElse(node);
        street = Optional.ofNullable(address.get("street")).map(JsonNode::asText).orElse(null);
        zip = Optional.ofNullable(address.get("zip")).map(JsonNode::asText).orElse(null);
        city = Optional.ofNullable(address.get("city")).map(JsonNode::asText).orElse(null);
}
```